# How to delete/unblock my server IP in iptables on Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, devops

My first server blocked my second server IP and I haven't access now.

Command `iptables -L -n | grep xx.xxx.xxx.xx`

give me result like:

```
ACCEPT     all  --  xx.xxx.xxx.xx        0.0.0.0/0
REJECT     all  --  xx.xxx.xxx.xx        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

The `xx.xxx.xxx.xx` is the same IP and it is my server IP.
I have two rules like ACCEPT AND REJECT for this IP.

How can I give access to my server IP from iptables and prevent blocking my IP ?

Many thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To recreate your issue

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 10.64.7.109 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s 10.64.7.109 -j REJECT
iptables -P INPUT DROP
```

but that will not block `10.64.7.109` and the first rule hit will be the accept

you are only sharing the output that specifically has the IP you are interested in so i can not see what rules above these 2 would be blocking it.

you can allow this `IP` by inserting a rule in position 1 which will resolve your issue but without seeing all your rules I can not say it is the most appropriate way to resolve the issue.

```
iptables -I  INPUT 1  -s 10.64.7.109 -j ACCEPT
```